# Matrix representation wrt bases

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, transition-matrix

Consider the function $T:P_{2}\to P_{3}$ given by $T(p(x)) = xp(x)$.
Let $\mathcal{B} = \{1, x, x^{2}\}$ be the ordered standard basis of $P_{2}$. Let $\mathcal{C} = \{2,x/2,3x^{2}, x^{3}-2\}$ be an ordered basis of $P_{3}$. Find the matrix representation of $T$ with respect to the bases $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{C}$.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDNC2.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Could you please show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: This is a standard problem. I believe your linear algebra textbook should have similar examples. For example, Section 2.2 of Linear Algebra by Friedberg et al. contains few similar examples.

Comment: @APCorreia thank you. I've added an image with what I've done so far but I'm not sure whether to proceed with1 or 2 I'm a bit confused sorry

Comment: @torontohrb yes but B is a ordered basis of P2 and C of P3. I haven't encountered questions like this previously

Comment: I think your last 4 by 3 matrix is the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  The columns will be $T$ applied to the elements of $\mathcal B$ (in order) expressed in terms of $\mathcal C$.